# CallContext.LogicalGetData Vs. CallContext.GetData

Tags: c#, .net

The `CallContext` API has `LogicalGetData` & `GetData`, but the MSDN Documentation doesn't do much to explain the difference between the two, and when they differ.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[It appears that this is a subtle difference related to method calls made remotely to another `AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx#remarksToggle). In this instance a `LogicalCallContext` is created and the data is stored in a manner accessible to `LogicalGetData`. While in normal, non-remoted method calls the data is stored in a manner accessible to `GetData`.

> When a remote method call is made to an object in another AppDomain, the CallContext class generates a LogicalCallContext instance that travels along with the remote call. Only objects that expose the ILogicalThreadAffinative interface and are stored in the CallContext are propagated outside the AppDomain in a LogicalCallContext. Objects that do not support this interface are not transmitted in LogicalCallContext instances with remote method calls.

`GetData`:

> Retrieves an object with the specified name from the `CallContext`.

`LogicalGetData`:

> Retrieves an object with the specified name from the logical call context.

Answer (score 64):

Generally, data stored via `CallContext.SetData` is considered to be thread local.  That is, any call to `CallContext.GetData` will get the data that was set via SetData from the same thread.  Data stored via `CallContext.LogicalSetData` is considered to be "logical thread" local.  That is, any data that is stored via `CallContext.LogicalSetData` will be "flowed" to any child threads.  If you call `CallContext.LogicalGetData` in the same thread or any child threads, you will get the data that was stored by that thread's (or the parent thread's) call to `CallContext.LogicalSetData`.

As @sixlettervariables points out, there are also some specific differences related to Remoting and cross AppDomain calls (maybe cross AppDomain implies Remoting, I don't know, I am not that familiar with Remoting in general).

Also as pointed out by @sixlettervariables, by implementing the marker interface ILogicalThreadAffinative on an object and then storing that object using `CallContext.SetData`, the object will essentially behave as if it had been stored by `CallContext.LogicalSetData`.

Here is a good blog posting from Jeff Richter about using LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2010/09/27/logical-call-context-flowing-data-across-threads-appdomains-and-processes.aspx

Here are some more links from here on SO that might shed some more light on CallContext.SetData/GetData, CallContext.LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData, and various forms of thread local storage:

[CallContext vs ThreadStatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273301/callcontext-vs-threadstatic)

[How to Pass a variable to another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969476/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-another-thread)

Comment: I believe it also flows, as part of the [ExecutionContext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/), between threads when using async/await and I'm assuming the same is true for this case - `Logical[Set|Get]Data` for non-`ILogicalThreadAffinative` implementers?